# Is it possible to create a dynamic arithmetic expression with a dynamic operator?

Tags: dynamic, swift, operators

I'd like to create a dynamic arithmetic expression with a dynamic operator.

I'm very new to swift, and the following is complete bogus, but I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
class Expr {
  var operandA:Double = 0;
  var operandB:Double = 0;
  var arithmeticOperator:operator = +; // total bogus

  init( a operandA:Double, b operandB:Double, o arithmeticOperator:operator ) {
    self.operandA = operandA;
    self.operandB = operandB;
    self.arithmeticOperator = arithmeticOperator;
  }

  func calculate() -> Double {
    return self.operandA self.arithmeticOperator self.operandB; // evaluate the expression, somehow
  }
}

var expr = Expr( a: 2, b: 5, o: * );
expr.calculate(); // 10
```

Would something similar be possible, somehow (without defining operation functions/methods, that is)?

Comment: Accept a lambda of type `(Double, Double) -> Double`. Then invoke it later, e.g. `arithmeticOperator(operandA, operandB)`. See [Functional Programming in the Swift Language](https://medium.com/swift-programming/2-functional-swift-c98be9533183) for a brief overview of this technique. Then this function can be defined elsewhere, and used as `Expr(2, 5, Operators.MUL)`.

Comment: @user2864740 I see what you mean, yeah. Perhaps I should just take that route, indeed. I was actually trying to avoid creating functions (not sure why exactly; probably lazyness :)), but I could give this a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest, I could get with that was using the custom character for the operator and then use switch case to evaluate the expression,

```
protocol Arithmetic{
  func + (a: Self, b: Self) -> Self
  func - (a:Self, b: Self ) -> Self
  func * (a:Self, b: Self ) -> Self
}

extension Int: Arithmetic {}
extension Double: Arithmetic {}
extension Float: Arithmetic {}


class Expr<T:Arithmetic>{
  let operand1: T
  let operand2: T
  let arithmeticOperator: Character

  init( a operandA:T, b operandB:T, o arithmeticOperator:Character) {
    operand1 = operandA
    operand2 = operandB
    self.arithmeticOperator = arithmeticOperator
  }

  func calculate() -> T? {
    switch arithmeticOperator{
      case "+":
      return operand1 + operand2
      case "*":
      return operand1 * operand2
      case "-":
      return operand1 - operand2
     default:
      return nil
    }
  }
}

var expr = Expr( a: 2, b: 5, o: "+" );
expr.calculate();
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks pretty neat already. I'm not entirely sure what the usage of the methods in the protocol `Arithmetic` are, in this case, though. Would you mind expanding on that?